# Limit AWS console by resource tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

It seems like there are 50 posts about limiting users to resources by the resource tag. But I think what I am missing is if it possible within the console. I have a Amazon directory service up and running with a awsapps.com/console site for logging in. I have a few test users within my IAM role where the policy is as follows. I want a user who logs in to only see the resources with the appropriate tag. This works in simulation, but does not in the console. I get an a error of "An error occurred fetching instance data: You are not authorized to perform this operation.".

So is it possible to limit on tag in the console? I know it is in the CLI.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",   
"Statement": [
    {
     "Action": [
        "elasticmapreduce:*",
        "ec2:*",
        "cloudwatch:*",
        "s3:*",
        "sdb:*",
        "iam:PassRole",
        "iam:ListRoles"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*",
    "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {"ec2:ResourceTag/critical": "true"}
            }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: `only see the resources with the appropriate tag` .. This is not possible. The `ResourceDisplay` cannot be controlled in a granular fashion. Either they can see the whole thing or nothing. If you want them to see the whole thing, then `Describe*` permission are needed. There are a number of post on google and on AWS forums regarding limitations of Resource Tags based access policy.

Comment: Is there a way to only let developers see dev machines and not show the production servers? I just want them to be able to start and stop their own machines.

Answer (score 2):

The AWS Management Console does is not capable of showing only a limited set of resources. The permissions required to show resources means they can see **all** resources. However, permissions can still be assigned to limit the **actions** they can take (eg only start/stop instances with a specific tag).

The Amazon EC2 management console has the ability to **filter** resources by tag, id, etc. This means that users could restrict their view of resources, but it does not prevent them from seeing ALL resources.

The Management Console also has [Resource Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsconsolehelpdocs/latest/gsg/what-are-resource-groups.html), which are a means of grouping resources by a property, such as a tag. Users can then view all resources that share this property.